# found '0' definitions of operator “*”

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I have this error when trying to compile my VHDL code. The purpose of the code is to multiply a 2 bit constant K by some 4-bit number in memory. There are some similar posts here with the same error, but I have been unable to solve the problem even after using those posts. I thought the problem might be I need to make K unsigned, but converting it still gives the same problem. I am stuck, so any ideas are welcomed

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity ROM_ent is
       port (CLK : in std_logic;
             RE : in std_logic;
             K : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
             ADDR : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
             RESULT : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end ROM_ent;

architecture ROM_arch of ROM_ent is

         type ROM is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

         constant Content: ROM := (
                  0=>"0000",
                  1=>"0001",
                  2=>"0010",
                  3=>"0011",
                  4=>"0100",
                  5=>"0101",
                  6=>"0110",
                  7=>"0111",
                  8=>"1000",
                  9=>"1001",
                  10=>"1010",
                  11=>"1011",
                  12=>"1100",
                  13=>"1101",
                  14=>"1110",
                  15=>"1111",
                  others=>"0000");

begin

     process(CLK,RE,K)

     begin

          --if (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
          if (rising_edge(CLK)) then
             if (RE = '1') then
                RESULT <= Content(to_integer(unsigned(ADDR))) * K;  --Gives error, 0 definitions of "*" operator
                --RESULT <= Content(to_integer(unsigned(ADDR)));  --This works fine (but doesnt do what I want obviously
             else
             RESULT <= "ZZZZ";
             end if;
          end if;

     end process;

end ROM_arch;
```

Comment: Please edit your question for readability.  You mention an error, but you don't post the text of the error message.  Also please look at the title, which mentions the "*" operator, and your text, which doesn't mention it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071640/errorhdlcompiler1731-found-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071640/errorhdlcompiler1731-found-0-definitions-of-operator-cannot-determine?r=SearchResults&s=6|65.2522
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570062/why-do-i-get-found-0-definitions-of-operator-when-adding-bit-vectors-ar?r=SearchResults&s=7|64.1360
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330985/vhdl-found-0-definition-of-operator?r=SearchResults&s=1|90.7773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VHDL is strictly typed language as you know. You have a bit type conversion problem in that statement you assign to `RESULT`. It should be -

```
RESULT <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(Content(to_integer(unsigned(ADDR)))) * unsigned(K));
```

Also the `RESULT` should be of size 6 bits. because you are multiplying 4 bits by 2 bits.

Some suggestions:

- No need of `RE` and `K` in the sensitivity list.
- You can avoid that else part for `RE` and simply latch the last result obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Both operands must be unsigned. And the result must be casted to std_logic_vector.
I.e. add 
.. std_logic_vector( unsigned(Content(to_....))) * unsigned(K) )